Are comma categories over categories with pullbacks semi-secretly preorders?
Here is exercise IV.5.3 of Mac Lane's CWM:
For $C$ a category with pullbacks, each arrow $f: a \to a'$ defines a functor
$(C \downarrow a) = f_* : (C \downarrow a) \to (C \downarrow a')$ which carries each object $x \to a$ of $(C \downarrow a)$ to the composite $x \to a \to a'$. Show that $f_*$ has a right adjoint $f^*$ with $f^*(x'\to a') = y \to a$ where $y$ is the vertex of the pullback of $a \to a' \leftarrow x'$.
I can calculate and prove the desired adjoint in the usual way, but since the question is asked in the section Adjoints for Preorders, I have to wonder if I'm not expected to show that $(C \downarrow a)$ and $(C \downarrow a')$ are preorders and $f_*$ and $f^*$ monotone functions so that Theorem 1 (the "Galois connection" theorem) may be applied.

No, slice categories are not preorders in general.

As @NaimFavier points out, general slice categories are not preorders. This already fails for any non-preorder category $\mathcal{C}$ with a terminal object $\ast$, by considering the slice $\mathcal{C}\,/\,\ast \cong \mathcal{C}$.
On the bright side, you just discovered the fact, that adjunctions (vastly) generalize Galois-connections, which is also nice :)
